# Regex for Currency with specific length in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using the following regex expression for currency in my input form fields: my requirement is maximum length of input field is 16 digit and after that decimal (**.**) then two digit. i try this expression but it not working. something wrong with my expression.

```
^(\d*\.\d{1,2}|\d+){0,16}$
```

**Valid**

```
 //space- if user leave input box as blank 
0
0.9
9999
9999.0
9999.00
9999999999999999.00
```

**Invalid**

```
0.00.
99999999999999999.00
999......000
AB999
$99.00
```

**Note**:-Alphabet and symbol will not allowed (only **.** will allow)

Comment: basically i have problem with length, if i remove **{0,16}** then it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d{0,16}(?:.\d{1,2})?$
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pJ9sZ4/1)